# Pandas MultiIndex not returning levels and labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, multi-index

I am learning about [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) `MultiIndex()` for the first time. Here I have two lists that I want to combine using the `MultiIndex()` function. the outcome I am expecting should have `levels` and `labels` but this is not the case here.

here is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

inside = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
outside = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
zipped = list(zip(inside, outside))
hier_zipped = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zipped)

hier_zipped
```

the expected outcome:

```py
MultiIndex(levels = [['a','b'],[1,2,3]], 
           labels = [[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]]
           )
```

the actual outcome:

```py
MultiIndex([('a', 1),
            ('a', 2),
            ('a', 3),
            ('b', 1),
            ('b', 2),
            ('b', 3)],
           )
```

Comment: If you meant `pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a','b'],[1,2,3]], codes=[[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]])`, the output is the same

Comment: @mozway what do you mean by "the output is the same" ?

Comment: Your expected output is identical to your actual outcome. Maybe clarify your question.

Comment: @mozway the actual output does not clarify the levels and labels.

Comment: That's just the representation that is this way, the actual objects are equal (see below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two codes are giving equal objects (Just note that `labels` should be `codes`), the representation of the MultiIndex does not show the levels/codes:

```
pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['a','b'],[1,2,3]], codes=[[0,0,0,1,1,1],[0,1,2,0,1,2]])
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex([('a', 1),
            ('a', 2),
            ('a', 3),
            ('b', 1),
            ('b', 2),
            ('b', 3)],
           )
```

If you want the levels and codes, use:

```
hier_zipped.levels
# FrozenList([['a', 'b'], [1, 2, 3]]),

hier_zipped.codes
# FrozenList([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])
```